# How to add virtual property of type Array using Keystone.js?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, keystonejs

This is my code for my model: 'Info' and its the tokens property that creates the problem.

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;
var Info = new keystone.List('Info');
Info.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    subtitle: { type: String, initial: true },
    content: { type: Types.Markdown, height: 500, initial: true },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', initial: true },
    date: { type: Types.Date, default: Date.now, initial: true },
    published: { type: Boolean, default: false, initial: true },
    tokens: { type: Array, virtual: true, noedit: true, collapse: true }
});

Info.defaultColumns = 'title, author, date|15%, published|15%'
Info.register();
```

When running the app i get:

```
Error: Unrecognised field constructor: function Array() { [native code] }
at List.field (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/lib/list.js:315:10)
at List.<anonymous> (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/lib/list.js:200:16)
at List.<anonymous> (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/lib/list.js:191:5)
at List.<anonymous> (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/lib/list.js:230:5)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:82:22)
at List.add (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/node_modules/keystone/lib/list.js:204:4)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bobmoff/Dropbox (Mobiento)/IMGNRY/Nordea/dev/code/rantebevis-cms/models/infos.js:4:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what you are planning to store / do with tokens, so if this doesn't answer your question please clarify :)

I'm guessing you either mean:

- an [array path](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-array-js) that's stored in the database, or
- a [virtual property](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) whose value is not stored but is calculated at runtime.

Both are possible by modifying the mongoose `schema` directly, rather than using Keystone's `add` method on the `List`.

To add an array path (so you could, for example, store an array of string tokens generated through some process on save) you would do this:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Info = new keystone.List('Info');
Info.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    subtitle: { type: String, initial: true },
    content: { type: Types.Markdown, height: 500, initial: true },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', initial: true },
    date: { type: Types.Date, default: Date.now, initial: true },
    published: { type: Boolean, default: false, initial: true }
});

Info.schema.add({
    tokens: { type: [String] }
});

Info.defaultColumns = 'title, author, date|15%, published|15%';
Info.register();
```

To create a virtual property, you'd specify it with a getter like this:

```
Info.schema.virtual('tokens', function() {
    var tokens = [];
    // calculate tokens somehow
    return tokens;
});
```

By accessing the schema you bypass Keystone's list, which means the fields won't show up in the Admin UI. There's [an issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone/issues/204) to add support for custom templates in the Admin UI though which will allow this in the future.

There's also an issue for an [array field type](https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone/issues/13), so if you are storing strings in an array for now you'll be able to include it in the Admin UI when that feature is implemented.

On a related note, all the functionality mongoose offers is available via the schema so you can define things like custom methods, statics and pre / post save hooks too. For more about what you can do with mongoose schemas, check out the [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Comment: I tried adding the tokens propety directly to the schema, and that works. But when I create a new Info item, it gets stored with an empty array in the tokens property. I just want this property to exist during the response in my API. It seems like on-the-fly-added properties gets removed when send in the response (using res.send(items);) I dont want to do the calculation inside the getter, coz that gives me to little controll when it happens.