# How can I create the array of strings in Keystone.js Database ODM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, mongoose, keystonejs

How can I create the array of strings in Keystone.js Database ODM? I have to create new model with single field and make a `many:true` relationship with him only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add virtual property of type Array using Keystone.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063884/how-to-add-virtual-property-of-type-array-using-keystone-js)

Comment: Some documentation about the solution of this (Types.TextArray) is avalable on Github https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/fields/types/textarray

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a field type for this:

```
Things.add({
  manyStrings: { type: Types.TextArray }
});
```

There is a similar field for numbers called `Types.NumberArray`.

If you want something more sophisticated, your best bet is creating a separate List and using the `Relationship` field.

Comment: Can we use array of other types? like Types.NumberArray

Comment: How come the documentation doesn't mention Types.TextArray?

Comment: @JedWatson the lack of documentation is killer!

Comment: +1 @ChrisRich Docs could be much better. Check `project/node_modules/keystone/fields/types` to see [all types](http://imgur.com/a/4aLwc).

Comment: @ChrisRich At the time of your comment, the TextArrays are not in the current old-but-stable v0.3.x documentation, while the Array types are of the v4.0.0-beta.4 or beta 5.
There is already some documentation about this on Github only https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/fields/types/textarray